# Spring Method Injection

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Reading the Spring 3 documentation I came to across Method Injection which I though might solve an issue I was having creating Prototype beans from my Singleton factory however I'm surprised by the documentation stating this:

"In most application scenarios, most beans in the container are singletons."

In my opinion this statement is misleading as I quite often find that I will need to create new instances at run time (which also benefit from dependency injection) but I find the Method Injection pattern a bit clumsy. An example of this would be where my application polled the database for new records created by the user through a front end and then created a new instance to service this record.

Can anybody shed some light on what this statement might mean and if it is true for most developers? I'd appreciate an answer which would include examples to help me understand and hopefully correct what I'm doing wrong (assuming this statement is true)

Answer (score 1):

I liked your question very much. After reading your question I found the following topic very interesting.
I recommend you to read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-modes) section of the Spring documentation. It cleared up my understanding of the same issue.

**Update**

I also noticed one very interesting point in this section of documentation is that when you have non-singleton bean in your application, spring is not capable of handling it after creating the instance. It depends on the client after that point.

Hope this helps you also. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback and link... this is very interesting and something that I did not realise. Just in case anybody else comes along this comment the Spring 3 document reference to the same topic can be found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Comment: Not sure it solves my problem, what I really need is more of an architectural discussion of Spring. However this is definitely a good point... thanks again.

Comment: Good luck for your architecture. :-)